# GUI Java Simple Calculator using ^

Tags: java, user-interface

I've made a simple calculator. What happens is I convert the user input to infixtopostfix and then evaluate it. Everything works fine except when the user does something like `3^2`, the program doesn't convert it to post fix correctly. It should be converting it to `32^` but it's converting it to `^32`. Could someone please explain to me what is wrong with my convert method that is causing this issue.

Convert method:

```
static String convert(String infix) 
       {
            ArrayStack<Character> as = new ArrayStack<Character>(infix.length());

            String post_expression = "";
            int index = 0;

            while(index < infix.length()) { 

                char current = infix.charAt(index);

                if(current == ' ') {
                index++;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(current == '(') {
                    as.push(current);
                }
                else if(current == ')') {
                    while(as.top() != '(') {
                        post_expression += as.pop();
                    }
                    as.pop(); 
                }
             else if(current == '=')
             {
                index++;
                continue;
             }
             else if(current == '^')
             {
                post_expression += as.pop();
             }

                else {

                    while(!as.isEmpty() && as.top() > current) {
                        post_expression += as.pop();
                    }
                    as.push(current);
                }

                index++;

            }

            while(!as.isEmpty()) {
                post_expression += as.pop();
            }

            return post_expression;

        }
```

Complete Program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Calculator2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
   JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
   JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
   JButton btn_add = new JButton("+");
   JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
   JButton btn5 = new JButton("5");
   JButton btn6 = new JButton("6");
   JButton btn_sub = new JButton("-");
   JButton btn7 = new JButton("7");
   JButton btn8 = new JButton("8");
   JButton btn9 = new JButton("9");
   JButton btn_mult = new JButton("*");
   JButton btn0 = new JButton("0");
   JButton btn_dot = new JButton(".");
   JButton btn_del = new JButton("DEL");
   JButton btn_div = new JButton("/");

   JButton btn_lpr = new JButton("(");
   JButton btn_rpr = new JButton(")");
   JButton btn_pow = new JButton("^");
   JButton btn_equ = new JButton("=");

   JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
   String str_number = "";

   public Calculator2() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Java Caculator");
      frame.setSize(320,420);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

      JPanel HeadPanel = new JPanel();
      JPanel NumberPanel = new JPanel();
      JPanel LabelPanel = new JPanel();

      LabelPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      HeadPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      NumberPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,4));
    //LabelPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      LabelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

      NumberPanel.add(btn1);
      btn1.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn2);
      btn2.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn3);
      btn3.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn_add);
      btn_add.addActionListener(this);

      NumberPanel.add(btn4);
      btn4.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn5);

      btn5.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn6);
      btn6.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn_sub);
      btn_sub.addActionListener(this);

      NumberPanel.add(btn7);
      btn7.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn8);
      btn8.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn9);
      btn9.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn_mult);
      btn_mult.addActionListener(this);

      NumberPanel.add(btn0);
      btn0.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn_dot);
      btn_dot.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn_del);
      btn_del.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn_div);
      btn_div.addActionListener(this);
      LabelPanel.add(txt);

    //LabelPanel.add(btn_equ);
      NumberPanel.add(btn_lpr);
      btn_lpr.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn_rpr);
      btn_rpr.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn_pow);
      btn_pow.addActionListener(this);
      NumberPanel.add(btn_equ);
      btn_equ.addActionListener(this);

      txt.setEditable(false);
    //btn_del.setEnabled(false);
      HeadPanel.add(new JLabel("A Java Calculator"));
      frame.add(LabelPanel);
      frame.add(NumberPanel);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      if(e.getSource()==btn1) {
         str_number+="1";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn2) {
         str_number+="2";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn3) {
         str_number+="3";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn4) {
         str_number+="4";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn5) {
         str_number+="5";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn6) {
         str_number+="6";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn7) {
         str_number+="7";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn8) {
         str_number+="8";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn9) {
         str_number+="9";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn0) {
         str_number+="0";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn_lpr) {
         str_number+="(";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn_rpr) {
         str_number+=")";
         txt.setText(str_number); }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn_pow) {
         str_number+="^";
         txt.setText(str_number); }

      else if(e.getSource()==btn_add) {
         str_number+="+";
         txt.setText(str_number);}
      else if(e.getSource()==btn_sub) {
         str_number+="-";
         txt.setText(str_number);}
      else if(e.getSource()==btn_mult) {
         str_number+="*";
         txt.setText(str_number);}
      else if(e.getSource()==btn_div) {
         str_number+="/";
         txt.setText(str_number);}
      else if(e.getSource()==btn_equ) {
         System.out.println("you clicked equal sign!");
         str_number+="=";   
         txt.setText(str_number);
         String expression = convert(str_number);
         double eval = evaluate(expression);
         str_number+=eval;
         txt.setText(str_number);

      }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn_dot) {
         System.out.println("you clicked dot button!");
         str_number+=".";   
         txt.setText(str_number);
      }
      else if(e.getSource()==btn_del) {
         System.out.println("you clicked DEL button!");
         if(str_number.length() > 0)
         {
            str_number = str_number.substring(0, str_number.length() - 1);
         }
         txt.setText(str_number); 


      }
   }

    static String convert(String infix) 
   {
        ArrayStack<Character> as = new ArrayStack<Character>(infix.length());

        String post_expression = "";
        int index = 0;

        while(index < infix.length()) { 

            char current = infix.charAt(index);

            if(current == ' ') {
            index++;
                continue;
            }
            else if(current == '(') {
                as.push(current);
            }
            else if(current == ')') {
                while(as.top() != '(') {
                    post_expression += as.pop();
                }
                as.pop(); 
            }
         else if(current == '=')
         {
            index++;
            continue;
         }
         else if(current == '^')
         {
            post_expression += as.pop();
         }

            else {

                while(!as.isEmpty() && as.top() > current) {
                    post_expression += as.pop();
                }
                as.push(current);
            }

            index++;

        }

        while(!as.isEmpty()) {
            post_expression += as.pop();
        }

        return post_expression;

    }
   static double evaluate(String postfix) {

      ArrayStack as = new ArrayStack(postfix.length());
      char nextChar = 'm';

      int index = 0;
      double temp = 0.00;

      while(index < postfix.length()) {

         char current = postfix.charAt(index);

         if(current == ' ') {
            index++;
            continue;
         }
         if(!(current == '+' || current == '-' || current == '*' || current == '/'))
         {
            as.push(current);
            temp = (double) (current - '0');
         }
         else {
            char a = (char) as.pop();
            char b = (char) as.pop();
            double c = (double) (a - '0');
            double d = (double) (b - '0');

            switch(current) {
               case '+' :
                  temp = d + c;
                  break;
               case '-' :
                  temp = d - c;
                  break;
               case '*' :
                  temp = d * c;
                  break;
               case '/' :
                  temp = d / c;
                  break;
               case '^' :
                  temp = Math.pow(d, c);
                  break;
            }
            as.push(nextChar);
            nextChar++;
         }

         index++;
      }
      if(as.size() == 1) {
         as.pop(); 
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("There is an error");
      }
      return temp;

   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Calculator2();

   }
}
```

ArrayStack code

```
public class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E> {


    protected int capacity;

    public static final int CAPACITY = 1000;

    protected E S[];

    protected int top = -1;

    public ArrayStack() {
        this(CAPACITY);
    }
    public ArrayStack(int cap) {
        capacity = cap;
        S = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return top+1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (top < 0);
    }

    @Override
    public E top() throws EmptyStackException {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyStackException("Stack is empty!");
        return S[top];
    }

    @Override
    public void push(E element) {
        if(size() == capacity)
            throw new FullStackException("Stack is full");
        S[++top] = element;
    }

    @Override
    public E pop() throws EmptyStackException {
        E element;
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyStackException("Stack is empty");
        element = S[top];
        S[top--] = null;
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s;
        s = "[";
        if(size() > 0) s += S[0];
        if(size() > 1)
            for(int i = 1; i <= size()-1; i++) {
                s += ", " + S[i];
            }
        return s + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your code in too much detail, but my guess is the problem is caused by calling pop(). A stack is First-In, Last-Out data structure.

I created a calculator program and I found it easier to add the operands to one structure and the operators to another.  And, if this character is being entered manually to the text field, create an input validator that restrict entering non-numeric characters.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Do you have a functioning version?

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo Added the other code that's needed.

Comment: Also fixed one part that wasn't allowing it to compile.

Comment: The biggest problem is that you haven't specified the language of the arithmetic expressions. What should be the result of evaluating "4 x 3 - 2"? Is it equivalent to "(4 x 3) - 2" or "4 x (3 - 2)"? Before you can do any useful parsing, you have to decide on the formal definition of your grammar.

Comment: I got this to start working. Now when I do any decimal numbers, it doesn't work properly. EX: 3.2 + 2.0